# IOS UDP recvfrom works when in Blocking but not when Non-Bocking

Tags: ios, sockets, udp

When I comment out the code that turn off blocking everything works fine, but when I leave the non blocking code in I never get any data from recvfrom. (Received bytes is always 0)  Here is the code with the blocking statement commented out.    I am new to Xcode and IOS but have created UDP code for .NET.

```
 // Create Socket
int Handle = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
if (Handle <=0){
    printf("Failed to create socket\n");
}

// Bind Socket
struct sockaddr_in address;
address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
address.sin_port = htons((unsigned short) 4966);
if (bind(Handle,(struct sockaddr *) &address, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))< 0){
    printf("Failed to Bind\n");
}//end if
printf("Bind Done\n");

// Set to non Blocking
int NonBlocking = 1;
//if (fcntl(Handle, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK, NonBlocking) == -1){
    printf("Faile to set nonblocking\n");
//}
Boolean ContinueLoop = true;

    unsigned char Packet_Data[256];
    unsigned int Maximum_Packet_Size = sizeof(Packet_Data);

    struct sockaddr_in From_Address;
    socklen_t FromLength = sizeof(From_Address);

     while (ContinueLoop){
    int Received_Bytes = recvfrom(Handle, (char *)Packet_Data, Maximum_Packet_Size, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&From_Address, &FromLength);



    if (Received_Bytes > 0){
        ContinueLoop = false;
        printf("Got Data \n");
    } else {
        perror("Now");
        printf(".");
    }



    close(Handle);

}//wend
```

Comment: 1. recvfrom() doesn't return zero when there is no data in non-blocking mode, it returns -1, with errno set to EWOULDBLOCK/EAGAIN. 2. Your O_NONBLOCK code is commented out, so I don't know how you can possibly make this assertion. 3. If recvfrom() returns -1 you should be handling an error, not just ignoring it. There might be something else going wrong. 4. You shouldn't be spinning like that in non-blocking mode anyway, you should be using select().

Comment: I realized that the no block is commented out and I stated that in the statement Here is the code with the blocking statement commented out.   I figure I would post the working code, and if you want the non working code you just remove them comments.  Thanks for the info on the error codes finding documentation is not easy.  From the debugger I am getting a 0 not -1.  For now I am taking baby steps.  My current goal is just to receive data.   Not do anything with it.  This is not final/production code.

Comment: When I run on the actual device and not the simulator I get a -1 and an error of bad file descriptor.  (But only when I include the non blocking statements.   If I comment them out as show above it works)

Comment: Here is the changed code 
        if (Received_Bytes > 0){
            ContinueLoop = false;
            printf("Got Data \n");
        } else {
            perror("Now");
            printf(".");
        }

Comment: The only way `recvfrom()` can return 0 is if it is actually receiving 0-length datagrams. Unlike TCP, UDP datagrams can have data payloads that are 0 bytes in size. Some protocols, like UDP-based `TIME`, actually depend on that.

Comment: I guess what I am trying to understand is why am I getting the data when blocking but not getting anything when nonblocking. My Mackbook and my PC are the only things connected to a sandbox network i created.  (Hardwired netgear hub, Wireless is turned off on macbook PC does not have wireless capability)   The PC is just sending UDP packets (infinite loop) of HELLO APPLE FROM THE PC.

Comment: Do the perror() calls now ever print anything?

Comment: On the actual device and not the simulator perror returns an error of Bad file Descriptor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.  I accidentally included the close statement inside the while loop.   Moved it out of the loop where it belongs and all is working now.  Blocking and nonblocking.